# JPA Criteria Query over an entity hierarchy using single table inheritance

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

Say I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class BaseEntity { 
    private Date someDate;
    private Date otherDate;
    private boolean flag;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("entity1")
public class Entity1 extends BaseEntity { 
    private String someProperty;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("entity2")
public class Entity2 extends BaseEntity { 
    private String otherProperty;
}
```

I'm trying to build a criteria query that returns instances of BaseEntity based on properties in BaseEntity and both of the subclasses. So essentially I'm looking for a criteria query that corresponds to this pseudo-SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM <BaseEntity table name>
WHERE someDate < ? AND otherDate > ? AND flag = ?
AND someProperty = ? AND otherProperty = ?;
```

I'd rather not build two separate queries since they have so much overlap (i.e. most of the properties are in the base class). However, I haven't figured out a way to reference the subclass properties in the query if I declare BaseEntity as the root. Is it possible to build a criteria query like this?

**UPDATE:**

Maybe some code would clarify the question. I'd essentially like to do something like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = ...;
CriteriaQuery<BaseEntity> query = ...;
Root<BaseEntity> root = ...;

query.select(root).where(builder.and(
        builder.lessThan(root.get(BaseEntity_.someDate), new Date()),
        builder.greaterThan(root.get(BaseEntity_.otherDate), new Date()),
        builder.isTrue(root.get(BaseEntity_.flag)),
        builder.equal(root.get(Entity1_.someProperty), "foo"),   <-- This won't work
        builder.equal(root.get(Entity2_.otherProperty), "bar")   <-- Neither will this
));
```

Now, I understand why the above code sample doesn't work, but I'd like to know if there's a way to get around it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to solve this by downcasting the BaseEntity root into new roots that correspond to the subclass types with [CriteriaBuilder.treat()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#treat(javax.persistence.criteria.Root,%20java.lang.Class)) like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = ...;
CriteriaQuery<BaseEntity> query = ...;
Root<BaseEntity> root = ...;
Root<Entity1> entity1 = builder.treat(root, Entity1.class);
Root<Entity2> entity2 = builder.treat(root, Entity2.class);

query.select(root).where(builder.and(
        builder.lessThan(root.get(BaseEntity_.someDate), new Date()),
        builder.greaterThan(root.get(BaseEntity_.otherDate), new Date()),
        builder.isTrue(root.get(BaseEntity_.flag)),
        builder.equal(entity1.get(Entity1_.someProperty), "foo"),
        builder.equal(entity2.get(Entity2_.otherProperty), "bar")
));
```

Comment: not working it gives null.someDate and null.otherDate, illegal error

Comment: It worked now, I don't what was wrong, but it suddenly started working

Comment: What if you only want to select entities of those specific type and don't wanna enforce any other condition?

Answer (score -2):

Try `Junction`. You can always do something like this:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(YourClassName.class);
Criterion cr1 = Restrictions.lt("propertyname", propertyvalue);
Criterion cr2 = Restrictions.gt("propertyname", propertyvalue);
Criterion cr3 = Restrictions.eq("propertyname", propertyvalue);
Criterion cr4 = Restrictions.eq("propertyname", propertyvalue);
Junction cond = Restrictions.conjunction();
cond.add(cr1).add(cr2).add(cr3).add(cr4)
crit.add(cond);
```

I hope I got your question Correctly.

Comment: That solution is based purely on Hibernate, but I'm looking for one based on the JPA Criteria API. Also, I'd rather use the JPA2 metamodel for referencing the properties rather than the string identifiers.

Comment: The op asked question of JPA, not hibernate.