# Can I select all super objects from an extended entity using single table inheritance in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, hibernate-mapping

I thought it was a good idea to use **single table inheritance** for my use case - the ability to store different content types in the one table. In my case storing different article types (link, text, image).

1. text (the base class)

   - articleId
   - text
2. link (extends of text)

   - super(articleId, text)
   - link
3. image (extends of text)

   - super(articleId, text)
   - image
   - imageDescription

I'm in the process of making a ***feed*** of different articles (image, text, and link), and came across the problem that I cannot `select * from text` and have the super classes included? Is there a way around this? Have I chosen the wrong database schema setup?

It'd be ideal if I could ***select all from text*** and have the link & image objects included.

Another problem I'm facing is whether I should use the one controller in spring for my `text, link, and image` classes? At the moment I've got 3 different controllers, and 3 different services for each of the extended entities?!

Answer (score 0):

Is text both a member and also an entity itself? I wouldn't recommend that. But I try to focus your controllers on the request and response interactions. You don't necessarily need a controller per an entity. I did this and I found it made my app revolve around the entities rather than the processes the user was trying to do. Definitely a Dao and Service per an entity, but a controller is about the user interacting with the app in my opinion.

I'm not sure about your question with querying the base table in hibernate though. I know you can do something like this in JPA with treat() [JPA Criteria Query over an entity hierarchy using single table inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25624768/jpa-criteria-query-over-an-entity-hierarchy-using-single-table-inheritance). But I wouldn't do that. Rather just have this functionality in the Text Service layer, which would have access to all the Daos needed. Ofcourse if you had hundreds of classes extending Text I would look for a solution of the type you are seeking, but seeing as you only have 3 I think that solution would be fine, you'll only have 3 daos there.

Doing this would also mean you won't need to worry about moving away from the single table policy.

So in the service layer it would just be:

```
List<String> texts = textDao.getAllText();
texts.addAll(linkDao.getAllText());
texts.addAll(imgDao.getAllText());
return texts;
```

Probably the easiest.